# Windows Server 2012 and IIS

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012

I have just installed Windows Server 2012 R2.

IIS is installed and running on the server.

When I go to browse to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1

I expect to get an IIS logo displayed - but it is not displaying

Instead I am getting a Windows logo and

Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
Remote Web Access

How do I get the server to display the IIS logo so that it will display a website when one is created?

Answer (score 0):

Check in **IIS Management** if you can see under sites the **default web site**. if you can see it then right click on it and "**explorer**" that will show you the default folder for IIS. it must be "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
Otherwise, you have something wrong with the installation. Remove IIS and install it again.

PS: use an administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the Windows Server Essentials Experience role installed which will display the page you are referring to. I have seen this deployed lately out of the box.

Please remove this role correctly by following the below:
Please use Clean up Windows Server Essentials wizard to clean up firstly. Then use Remove Roles and Features Wizard to remove the Windows Server Essentials Experience role.

And once done, remove the IIS service via add and remove features.
Reboot the server, re-add the IIS service via add and remove features and retest.

Alternatively, check that IIS manager is correctly configured.
Expand Server - Sites - Right-click the Default site and select advanced settings and ensure your path is correct. You can also double check your default document value to ensure the right page is loaded.

Regards,
WK